# Is it possible to declare object type used as a method input

Tags: python, object

I have a class with many attributes, something like:

```
    class Person:
       name
       age
```

Assume that i created an object of this class, and send it as input to a method in another module:

```
    person = Person()
    add_info(person)

    def add_info(p):
        p.name = 'Joe'
        p.age  = 10
```

While adding attributes to object 'p', the method doesn't have any clue that this is a type Person object, hence it doesn't have any clue about if 'p.name' or 'p.age' are something valid or not.

is there something in python, like Java, to identify the input type used in a method? Such as:

```
    def add_info(Person p):
```

Comment: You should look at two python built-in functions: `isinstance` and `hasattr`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? We can give you options, but different options solve different problems.

Comment: You should read about "duck typing"

Comment: Python (since 3.5) has the feature to add type hints to method arguments. They are for documentation and don't enforce static typing.

Answer (score 0):

Opss. found it, works a below:

```
    def add_info(p: Person):
```